# Unable to connect to MongoDb (MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

these days i have tried to fix the db connection error but unfortunately i haven't got any solution for the error

when I am trying to run the server its getting an error like

```
server is running on the port : 5000
Unable to connect to the Mongo db  MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.222.222.176:27017
failed to connect to MongoDB MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.222.222.176:27017
```

below is the server code of node js and mongo db

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

const app=express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri,{ useNewUrlParser: true ,useCreateIndex:true,useUnifiedTopology: true})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log(`Unable to connect to the Mongo db  ${error} `);
});


const connection =mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open',()=>{
console.log("MongoDB connection established successfully");
})

mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
    console.log(`failed to connect to MongoDB ${err}`)
  });




const userRouter = require('./routes/users');
const productRouter = require('./routes/products');

app.use('/users',userRouter);
app.use('/product',productRouter);

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`server is running on the port : ${port}`);
});
```

I have tried to change the network from home to office in home its working fine. But when I am trying to run in office machine its getting the above error. I have checked the creds of mongo db and its working fine with the uri which they provide while connection.

Please anyone figure out the issue for me. Solutions will be appreciable.

Comment: Try to pass instead of `uri` hardcoded string. What's the result?

Comment: I have tried. but still getting the same error :(

Comment: Have you whitelisted your office IP in Atlas?

Comment: yes i have tried to add both 0.0.0.0/0 and office ip address both didnt work for me

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem for an half an hour or so but it was not an issue after that. I changed nothing in my code or my firewall settings. Just waited a bit and the program worked as usual. So I think this may be something that is wrong with the Mongodb servers or it may be due to a slow network connection. Maybe check the uri and just waiting for a while. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably yo can check for the following

```
1. Make sure the mongoDB is running on the specified machine.
2. Make sure the bindIP in config is modified to accept connection from other IPs
```

Comment: I am using Mongo db atlas platform so that i havent installed any software in my machine and i have changed the network access to 0.0.0.0/0 so that i can access from any machine. correct me if I am wrong please

Comment: @Angular Stack Can able to ping to that machine(3.222.222.176) from ur machine??

Comment: could u please tell me how to ping to that system

Comment: just use command `ping IP` in terminal if linux or cmd prompt(windows)

Comment: But that system not required to run the server right? because its taking data from cloud

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it occurs due to a low internet connection so you should always use **async and await** to avoid that type of errors

```
const connectDB = async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(`Unable to connect to the Mongo db  ${error} `);
        });
//...rest of code
};

// use as a function        
connectDB();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when I connected to my laptop with my office internet and once I changed my internet connection,now it is working.
Note: you need change something in your pc Firewall setting.you can visit this link to know more about firewall [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/automatically-diagnose-and-fix-problems-with-windows-firewall-513e9cf8-19ae-d579-2092-d5e64fe06f5f)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and it worked for me when I stopped the VPN I was using in my laptop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

** it is because ,that you have slow internet or any network problem , the latency should be lower than 100ms.**
i have this problem at my project, at first i thought it should be a error in database connection, so i tried mongoose options, obviously it didnt work. so i search through internet for soultion,at last i came this page.then i changed 5G to 4G, beacuse i was using my mobile hotspot, in my area i did not 5G Speeds consistent.but after trying my stable 4G speeds i was able to connect the Database easily

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem. I just reconnect the wifi again then its good to go.
You should check the internet connection and reconnect them with your computer/laptop.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32325656)